# Finding cartesian equation from parametric trigonometric equations

Tags: calculus, parametric

I'm trying to find the cartesian equation of the curve which is defined parametrically by:

$$
x = 2\sin\theta, y = \cos^2\theta
$$

Both approaches I take result in the same answer:

$$
y = 1 - \sin^2\theta\\
\sin \theta = \sqrt{y-1} \\
x = 2\sqrt{y-1} \\
x^2 = 4(y- 1) \\
x^2 + 4 = 4y
$$
Method 2:
$$
\sin^2 = y - 1 \\
\sin\theta = \frac{x}{2} \\
\sin^2\theta = \frac{x^2}{4} \\
x^2 + 4 = 4y
$$

But the answer listed is $x^2 + 4y^2 = 4$. Are my calculations wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your calculation. Note that 
$$\sin^2\theta\not=y-1$$
and that 
$$\sin^2\theta=1-y.$$

By the way, I think you have a typo in your question.

If $x=2\sin\theta,y=\cos^2\theta$ are correct, then since 
$$\sin^2\theta=\left(\frac x2\right)^2,\ \ \cos^2\theta=y,$$
we have
$$\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\Rightarrow y+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2=1\Rightarrow y=-\frac{x^2}{4}+1.$$

Note that this is not $x^2+4y^2=4$.

Comment: I guess it's a typo then. Very annoying! :)

Comment: I know this probably isn't the best place, but I'm having trouble with another parametric equation: $x=t^3-6t+4, y=t-3+\frac{t}{2}$. I'm supposed to find the point of intersection between the cartesian equation and its normal to the curve at the point where the curve meets the x-axis

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{x}{2}=\sin \theta.$ Now,

$$1=\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+y,$$

from where

$$x^2+4y=4.$$

Note that $y=\cos^2\theta \le 1.$ So it doesn't makes sense $\sqrt{y-1}$ unless $y=1$ (or you are working on complex numbers, what is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
Squring each equation and multiplying the last on by 4 we get
$$
\begin{align}
x^2&=4sin^2\theta\\
4y^2&=4cos^2\theta\\
\end{align}
$$
Adding the above two equations we get
$$
\begin{align}
x^2+4y^2&=4(cos^2\theta+sin^2\theta)\\
&=4
\end{align}
$$
Where we used the identity $cos^2\theta+sin^2\theta=1$.